# Can I send build statuses from Jenkins to Gitlab when manually launched?

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to send build statuses not by Gitlab trigger but by manually starting the job. I tried standard configuartion which works for case when Gitlab triggers the job, but can I achieve this if I start job manially and specify branch? Did not find any info on this use case in Gitlab plugin docs. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

i had similar problems with the bitbucket plugin. i solved the problem by setting the buildstatus directly with curl in the pipeline instead of using the plugin.

you can also use curl in your jenkins pipeline to post the buildstatus via the gitlab rest api. set the status to running in the first stage and set success or failed in the post section.

Link to [“set status of a commit"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#set-the-pipeline-status-of-a-commit)

example:

```
pipeline {
agent any
environment {
    GITLAB_TOKEN=credentials('your_access_token')
}
stages {
    stage('Set Gitlab Buildstatus: running')
    {
        steps {
            sh 'curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8?state=running"'
        }
    }
    stage('your stages')
    {
        echo "your stage"
    }
}
post {
    success {
        sh 'curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8?state=success"'
    }
    unsuccessful {
        sh 'curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/17/statuses/18f3e63d05582537db6d183d9d557be09e1f90c8?state=failed"'
    }
}
```

}